# jquery html duplicating on drag and drop

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery and using a drag and drop function.  My image keeps duplicating and I have no idea why. Any help would be great. I am pretty sure my issue is at line:

```
$('#' + seat).append('<div class="studentCard" id="' + id + '"><img class="studentImage" src="Images/' + id + '.jpg" style="height:150px; width:150px;" />' + student + '</div>');
```

Here is my function:

```
$('.seat').droppable({        
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var seat = $(this).attr('id');
        var id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        var student = $(ui.draggable).html();
        $.ajax({
            success: function () {
                if ($('#' + seat + '> div').length > 0) {
                    alert('Desk already occupied');
                }
                else {                   
                    $(ui.draggable).remove();
                    $('#' + seat).append('<div class="studentCard" id="' + id + '"><img class="studentImage" src="Images/' + id + '.jpg" style="height:150px; width:150px;" />' + student + '</div>');
                    $('div#' + id).draggable({
                        helper: 'clone'
                    });                        
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `append()` is intended to add new content. If you call it multiple times then it will result in duplicate content. You could check to see if the image already exists and not call `append()`. What behaviour are you trying to create?

Comment: How about using a different id for each new image? (Try adding a number counter to the end of the id so you get id1, id2, etc to make the id unique)...

Comment: Or not use an ID at all - never a need for an incrementing ID.   `$("..").append("div id="+(n+1)... $("div#" + id).event` could be `$("div").appendTo("..").event`

Comment: @freedomn-m just a note, running it twice would re-initialize the droppable and `drop` event would only run once.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It's possible the draggable helper is still appearing and when you append, you're not removing all the items you expect to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example. You might also consider using Sortable instead.

```js
$(function() {
  function moveStudent(source, target) {
    $(target).append($(".student", source).detach());
  }
  $(".student").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 100
  });
  $(".seat").droppable({
    accept: function() {
      if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      moveStudent(ui.draggable.parent(), this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.seat {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.student {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 5px;
}

.studentName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="seat-1" class="seat ui-widget-header">
  <div id="student-1" class="student" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/QjxuZB5.png');" data-student-id="1001">
    <div class="studentName">Thomas</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="seat-2" class="seat ui-widget-header">
  <div id="student-2" class="student" style="background-image: url('https://imgur.com/Gvmj4y5.png');" data-student-id="1002">
    <div class="studentName">Trinity</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="seat-3" class="seat ui-widget-header">
</div>
<div id="seat-4" class="seat ui-widget-header">
</div>
```

Instead of creating a new element, you can use `.detach()` and more easily move the original draggable item to the new drop zone.

It is sometimes better to use `accept` option to determine if a droppable should accept an item or not. This option does allow the use of a Function:

> **Function:** A function that will be called for each draggable on the page (passed as the first argument to the function). The function must return `true` if the draggable should be accepted.

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept

This allows you to re-arrange the items without stacking.